# What is the difference between Yoneda and Smyth-completeness?

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces

What is the difference between Yoneda and Smyth-completeness. I know that Smyth-completeness is a stronger property than Yoneda-completeness; however, I was unable to find a simple definition for both of them on Google as most references were linked to research papers about the subject.

Comment: Please put your question in the body of the post as well as in the title. Also please provide your thoughts/attempts on the question.

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.7.5764&rep=rep1&type=pdf goes into the differences. But that's too technical?

Comment: Thank you, seemed to be exactly what I was looking for.